# I'm unable to connect to socket

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to connect to a socket.But I did not get the socketid on the console.Is it the right way of connecting to a socket ?Can anyone please suggest me ...

My code :

```
var app = express();
var dir =  process.cwd();
app.use(express.static(dir)); //app public directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname)); //module directory
var server =require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);



io.of('/socket_issue').on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log("Socket connected :"+socket.id);
 socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    });
```

client code :

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:8085/socket_issue');
  socket.on('connect', function(){ console.log('connected to socket'); });
  socket.on('error', function(e){ console.log('error' + e); });

socket.on( 'news', function( data ){
console.log(data);

});
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
```

Comment: How are you trying to connect to the socket? All I'm seeing is the server side.

Comment: I had edited my client code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to not have a `server.listen()` in your backend code.
I've edited the server code and it functions correctly:

```
var app = require('express')();
var dir =  process.cwd();
var server =require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(8080);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


io.of('/socket_issue').on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log("Socket connected :"+socket.id);
 socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
});
```

Don't forget to change the port on the front-end and it'll work as expected:

```
Socket connected :Y7zi7dLRxqBA5nakAAAA
```

Comment: can you please suggest the best method to learn node.js,since I'm a novice to node.js

Comment: Learn by doing stuff. Google stuff a lot and you'll find everything.